# Precipitation percentage unit

Tags: here-api, weather

It used to be that `precipitationProbability` was in units of percentage points.  For example, if there were a 50% chance of rain, the API would return `50`.

Recently, the units seem to have changed to hundredths of percentage points.  For example, I'm seeing numbers ranging from 200-3800.  Is this intended, or is this a bug?  If it's intended, will the API documentation be updated to reflect this?  Here are the docs I'm referencing:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/destination-weather/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-weather-items.html

Answer (score 0):

We have reviewed this resource retrieves weather reports. Severe weather alerts be requested by setting the product parameter to alerts, and setting the name parameter to the required location in the request URL.

Link : https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/auto_weather

It worked perfectly fine for us , please check the attached screenshot.

Also, “metric parameter”. If set to false, the response contains imperial units (feet, inch, Fahrenheit, miles).
Default: true

Please check the following link to review the same(use API key).

https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?name=berlin&product=forecast_hourly&oneobservation=true&metric=false&apikey=&jsonpCallback=jsonp_callback_53724

Comment: One day after I posted my question, I checked it again, and the units were back to normal.  I thought you had fixed it, but maybe it was a temporary glitch of some sort?